# C# numericUpDown time validate

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make this code simpler?

```
private void hourNumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hourNumericUpDown.Value == 0 & minutesNumericUpDown.Value == 0) { okButton.Enabled = false; } else okButton.Enabled = true;
    // same in minutesNumericUpDown's event
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 1: button3 should actually be okButton too in OP's question.
Update 2: this is a timer

I am assuming that you want:

- OK button enabled when Hours > 0 **or** Minutes > 0

Try:

```
okButton.Enabled = hourNumericUpDown.Value > 0 || minutesNumericUpDown.Value > 0;
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be || instead of &&?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to do. Are you creating a timer (in which case we want either hours or minutes to be > 0 and minutes between 0 and 59), or is it a clock (in which case we want hours between 0 and 23 and minutes between 0 and 59)?

Comment: Yep, the principle of timer.